# General method for evaluating series as definite integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, reference-request, power-series

I've come across some type of integration method on youtube in which you sort of "transform" the inside of the series into a definite integral. I dont really know the name/conditions of that procedure since the information online seems quite limited, but at a glance it seems pretty powerful.

Comment: Probably want the Euler-Maclaurin formula, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula

Comment: It would help if you put in a link to the video, or even just gave its address, so that we could see what you are talking about.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Thanks a lot!!!